# Jquery parse HTML modify contents and return HTML string

Tags: jquery, dom

What I am trying to do here is to modify child elements and add code before and after the matched elements, then return full HTML string to update a template file.

So far this has been successful but one small problem which I can not seem to solve.
for example:

```
var htmlObj = $('<div/>').html(html).contents();
$htmlDom    = htmlObj.parent().find('*');

$htmlDom.each(function(i, el) {
   if(typeof($(el).data('key')) !== 'undefined') {
      $(el).before(codeBefore);
      $(el).after(codeAfter);
   }
});

html = $htmlDom.html();
```

Now this works fine to add the code before and after.
But the problem is if the markup is different for example: everything is wrapped around

This 1st line of html with  is ignored unless I change to `$htmlDom.parent().html();`
And if there is for example additional  wrap then to get this line to work I need to change to `$htmlDom.parent().parent().html();`

The problem is the markup will be dynamic so we don't know if the code will be wrapped or which HTML tags are used. So what I need here is a way to modify the html output to string the full markup.

Answer (score 0):

4hrs and no one has offered any solution for this issue.

Thankfully I was able to solve this issue using a custom outerHTML function I found here which seems to work with every type of html markup.
[Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
html = $($htmlDom).outerHTML();

jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
return s
    ? this.before(s).remove()
    : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this paper will help you : http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Revealing-the-magic-how-to-properly-convert-HTML-string-to-a-DOM-element